# Firebase get adoption rate by Active Users

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have an app that has users in multiple countries, I am trying to find the **adoption rate by active users for the newer app version for a specific country(US as of now).**
I can see the total user and users who have different app versions but it does not show me active user information. Also, I can see the adoption rate under `latest Release` but that shows aggregated sum for all users in all the countries.

Any idea how I can get active user adoption rate filtered by country?

Answer (score 0):

use Google Analytics for that.

you can enable the usage of Google Analytics from Firebase Console.

[image: firebase2]

Comment: @ReyRey was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?